# Bokeh Extremely Slow in Flask

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I am having an issue where Bokeh code that runs blazing fast by itself is outrageously slow in Flask.

The function:

```
@app.route('/overview/')
def overview_view():

    times = [datetime.datetime.now(),]

    occs = mss[['cd', 'id', 'occ_pct']]

    occ_hist = bokeh.charts.Histogram(occs, 'occ_pct', bins = 20, title = 'Historical Occ %')

    times.append(datetime.datetime.now())

    occ_script, occ_div = bokeh.embed.components(occ_hist)

    times.append(datetime.datetime.now())

    html = flask.render_template(
        "summary.html",
        occ_script = occ_script,
        occ_div = occ_div,
        js_resources=js_resources,
        css_resources=css_resources,
        times = times)

    times.append(datetime.datetime.now())
    print(times)

    return html
```

occs is a dataframe of shape (1368, 3).

js_resources = bokeh.resources.INLINE.render_js()

css_resources = bokeh.resources.INLINE.render_css()

The problem:

The first few lines of code (through the first three "times" commands) take

- Almost no time (< 1 second) to run in a code window, outside the flask function
- Way too long (> 20 seconds) to run when I go to the webpage.

I've used the timestamps to identify where the slowdown is (unless there's some interaction I don't understand?), and it appears to be building the histogram. If I remove the histogram, or make it trivially easy, the page pops right up.

If I increase the # of bins (or leave it off) it can take > 100 seconds before those lines of code finish, while if I run them in a console they never take more than 5 seconds to finish.

Can anyone suggest why building the histogram is so much slower in the Flask view?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, however, I feel compelled to mention that the `bkcharts` project (formerly `bokeh.charts` API) is effectively unmaintained at this point. It had numerous problems and none of the people who previously worked on it still do. I *very strongly* suggest that you look at Holoviews for a Very High Level API on top of Bokeh. It is already better than `bokeh.charts` and also very actively maintained. It will be the officially endorsed and promoted High Level API going forward. See eg. http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Histogram.html#bokeh-gallery-histogram

Comment: Holoviews is new to me! I will do some reading to learn more about it.

In the meantime, I've been playing with other Bokeh charts, and they all seem fine. If it's just Histogram that's giving me trouble, I can just create the histogram data and use charts instead.

But I'll look at Holoviews to potentially replace all the charts. (I'm new, so such changes are pretty painful)

Comment: FYI I will be helping the Holoviews devs deliver a tutorial about Holoviews and Bokeh at the SciPy 2017 conference in about ten days. The tutorial video will be up on Youtube shortly after.